# If nth character of a string in a dataframe is a certain character delete that row

Tags: python, database, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 = {'seq': ["(((...))).(.)", "...((.))", "..(.)..(.)"],

       'a':  [1,3,5],
        'b': [9,4,7],
        'val': [0.01, 0.02, 0.03],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame (df1, columns = ['seq','a','b','val'])
```

And I want to specify that if the nth character of 'seq' is a "." then delete that row, where n is specified by the 'a' column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` and boolean indexing:

```
df1 = df1[df1.apply(lambda r: r['seq'][r['a']-1]!='.', axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
             seq  a  b   val
0  (((...))).(.)  1  9  0.01
2     ..(.)..(.)  5  7  0.03
```

Comment: as strings start at [0] how do i make this so that the 'a' value is 1 less than whats stated?

Comment: @DanynPatel simple subtraction. see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str.split` with `''` to split each character in a new column, then use indexing to get the right character at the position depending on the column a. finally check where != of '.'.

```
print (df1[df1['seq'].str.split('', expand=True)
                     .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df1)), df1['a']] #no need of -1 here
           !='.'])
             seq  a  b   val
0  (((...))).(.)  1  9  0.01
2     ..(.)..(.)  5  7  0.03
```

for a small dataframe of 3 rows, `apply` if faster, but if the size increases, this method becomes interesting. Although if the strings in seq are longer, they might be an effect on the timing.

```
%timeit df1[df1.apply(lambda r: r['seq'][r['a']-1]!='.', axis=1)]
# 1.15 ms ± 23.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit df1[df1['seq'].str.split('', expand=True).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df1)), df1['a']]!='.']
#1.7 ms ± 95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#with 300 rows
df2 = pd.concat([df1]*100)
%timeit df2[df2.apply(lambda r: r['seq'][r['a']-1]!='.', axis=1)]
# 7.45 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit df2[df2['seq'].str.split('', expand=True).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df2)), df2['a']]!='.']
#2.58 ms ± 52.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#with 3000 rows
df3 = pd.concat([df1]*1000)
%timeit df3[df3.apply(lambda r: r['seq'][r['a']-1]!='.', axis=1)]
#67.9 ms ± 3.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit df3[df3['seq'].str.split('', expand=True).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df3)), df3['a']]!='.']
#11.4 ms ± 432 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```